# remove css class from wordpress using jquery / javscript

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

```html
<section class="page__title-area page__title-height page__title-overlay page__title-wrapper d-flex align-items-center " data-background="https://dev.itpt.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Untitled-1.png" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://dev.itpt.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Untitled-1.png&quot;);">
<div class="container">
   </div>
</section>
```

From the above code, i want to delete class "page__title-overlay" through fronted javascript or jquery code, as i don't have access to wordpress core file like, functions.php. Can someone help

Comment: I have tried to add code to a custom js plugin but it didn't work  <script> jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

        $("section.page__title-area").removeClass(".page__title-overlay");
      
}); </script>

Comment: "Didn't work" is also utterly vague and tells us little. Did you check the console for errors? Does the plugin want JS code to be added _with_ `script` tags to begin with?

Comment: Hi Bro, I Just Replace Below JQuery (Code

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('section').removeClass('page__title-overlay'); 
});

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('section').removeClass('page__title-overlay');
```

});